# Token response is returned when using Trusted Origin in Direct Line OAuth

Tags: azure, bots, bug-tracking

I have added trusted origins in direct line with help of Microsoft document.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-directline?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#configure-enhanced-authentication

We have provided the url of web app in which the application is hosted and its working fine in Chrome browser.
But we are still getting the verification code in Safari , Firefox and sometimes in Chrome incognito when we have more than one account suggestions to sign in.

How to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The configuration the site options have the option to configure the sites with 3.0 version which is the Direct Line protocol and must be enabled for entire application. Then it will get access to all the browsers without any issue.
In enhanced authentication options, we need to **enable** the toggle and add the trusted origin of the websites that need to get access of additional protection without any explicit login.

[image]

Whenever we are providing the information regarding authentication of the bot, we need to provide the key token in the header initially. The format of the header will be like Authorization: Bearer SECRET_OR_TOKEN .
Checkout the additional procedure which is optional in this case and might be useful in future from Generate a [Direct Line Token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#generate-token)

Comment: We have tried this already. Enabled Enhanced authentication option and provided the link of ui url where the application is hosted. But still we are getting the magic token in all the browsers including Chrome , Firefox and Safari.